# ROMable (but complex) array of (ROMable) objects - how to solve it?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, rom

I'm working on a firmware for a MCU (ARM Cortex-M3). These devices don't have a lot of RAM, so by all means you should try to put data in constant memory (flash).

The problem goes like this: The device has to provide "registers" that would be read by an interface (MODBUS), so the operator reads "address" 10 and gets some number, he/she "writes" to "address" 101 and it causes some action etc. There will be hundreds of these "addresses" and access to them causes some action - for example a read from 1-10 causes a measurement of temperature on sensors 1 to 10, a read from 11-20 causes reading of some calibration values, a write to these addresses causes these calibration values to be stored on non-volatile memory etc. - there will be lot's of different functionalities (;

Currently I have it implemented like this:

1. there's one array which binds the address to callback function for read and write - one callback function can be bound to multiple addresses (like in the example above the same callback would be used for 1-10)
2. there are another arrays that bind address to parameters for callback, there are many arrays like that as the parameters may be of different type/size - in the example above there would be one array of structs {int address; int sensor;} for 1-10 and an array of structs {int address; int id; int size; int min; int max; int default;} for 11-20.
3. each callback can obtain current address, find related struct in it's array and get the parameters it needs

This approach is a bit repetitive, as I have to state addresses multiple times - there's an entry {1, readSensor, writeSensor} in main array, and another entry with address 1 in the array or sensors {1, 0x5423} - it just doesn't fit into DRY principle (;

One solution I've thought about was an array of polymorphic objects, but:

<strike>a. virtual functions cause the object to be placed in RAM (it's not ROMable)</strike> **EDIT:** It seems that this is caused by GCC bug, in 4.6 constexpr constructor causes the object to be placed in RAM, but for 4.7 it works!

b. this is still a bit cumbersome, as I have to create the object "somewhere", and put it's address in the array (the array would actually be placed in flash)

I can't use any STL stuff like vectors, as that is placed completely in RAM.

I've thought about some template-magic, but that would rather be black-magic (;

I've also thought about a linked list, but I just don't see any "nice" way to declare it in an readable and continuous form (like an array [; ), but I may be not familiar with some nice solution to this problem.

The simpliest solution would be to make callbacks accept another "void *" parameter and cast that to anything they need inside, but that's "not nice" and also requires me to create the structs with parameters "somewhere" and then bind them to the main array.

Any ideas for an elegant solution? This HAS to be in ROM, there will be hundreds of entries and each of them can have multiple different parameters.

Comment: Regarding the comment: "***so by all means you should try to put data in constant memory (flash)***", you should note much of that Cortex-M3's performance of 1.25MIPS/MHz relies on its Harvard architecture.  By forcing data and instruction fetches on the same bus, you may considerably impact performance.

Comment: It has caches, so only the first fetch of a given memory location is goingt to be "slow".

Comment: It seems that I might have dropped the polymorphic solution too soon - with GCC 4.6 object with trivial constructor (which is obligatory for polymorphic classes) is placed in RAM, even if it's marked with constexpr, but for GCC 4.7 it seems to be working (;

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably write some code to come up with the "source" for this, and sort of have a "compiler".

So your original source for this would be something like this:

```
# INPUT_SENSOR(callback1, callback2, address, sensor_id)
SENSOR(read_sensor, write_sensor, 100, 1)
SENSOR(read_sensor, write_sensor, 104, 2)
 ...
# CALIBTRATE(callback1, callback2, id, address, size, min, max, default)
CALIBRATE(calib_write, calib_read, 1, 44, 11, 18, 99, 33)
CALIBRATE(calib_write, calib_read, 2, 45, 12, 19, 98, 34)
```

You can then let that generate a data structure like this:

```
struct funcptrs {
   int (*readfunc)(int count, int arr[]); 
   void (*writefunc)(int count, int arr[]); 
   int count;
   int *arr; 
};

static const int arr1[] = { 100, 1 };
static const int arr2[] = { 104, 2 };

static const int arr3[] = { 1, 44, 11, 18, 99, 33 };
static const int arr4[] = { 2, 45, 12, 19, 98, 34 };

struct funcptrs functable[] = 
{
    { read_sensor, write_sensor, 2, arr1 },
    { read_sensor, write_sensor, 2, arr2 },
    { calib_write, calib_read, 6, arr3 }, 
    { calib_write, calib_read, 6, arr4 }, 
};
```

It may be possible to come up with this using a C preprocessor and run through it twice, perhaps - I have done that sort if thing in the past, but I'm a bit too lazy to try it out here - I think I'd rather write a 20-30 line piece of C code to produce the code, as it's both more flexible and usually easier to understand/follow.

Comment: Nice idea - I didn't think of that (; Anyway I'd still prefer a "native" solution if anyone has any clever way (that is not black magic [; ).

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely opt for a `switch .. case` statement.  It is very likely that your compiler will resolve it to a [branch table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table), which is as efficient as the callback function vector you implemented, but much more readable, in my opinion.  It goes like this:

```
void parse_modbus (int register, bool write, int more_parameters) {
    switch (register) {

    case TEMPERATURE_REGISTER_1:
    ...
    case TEMPERATURE_REGISTER_10:
        read_temperature(register - TEMPERATURE_REGISTER_1);
        break;

    case CALIBRATION_REGISTER_1:
    ...
    case CALIBRATION_REGISTER_10:
        if (write)
            write_calibration(register - CALIBRATION_REGISTER_1);
        else
            read_calibration((register - CALIBRATION_REGISTER_1);
        break;

    default:
        unimplemented_register(register);
        break;
    }
}
```

You still need look-up tables for min-max limits, though.

Answer (score 2):

We solved this with X-Macros.

The idea is to create a *readable* file with the registers, which will create the appropiate code by including it mulitple times.

- register.h

```
typdef enum {
  MR_SET_VOLTAGE = 100,  // 8bit-Register for the voltage R/W
  MR_SET_CURRENT = 104,  // 8bit-Register for the current R/W
  MR_ACT_VOLTAGE = 206,  // 16bit-Register for the actual Voltage Read-Only
} teRegister;
```

- allRegister.inc

```
REGISTER(uint8_t,MR_SET_VOLTAGE,readFnA,writeFnA)
REGISTER(uint8_t,MR_SET_CURRENT,readFnA,writeFnA)
REGISTER(uint16_t,MR_ACT_VOLTAGE,readFnB,NULL)
```

- register.c

```
#define PASTE(a,b)  a##b
#define REGISTER(_type,_regName,_readCallback,_writeCallback) \
    static _type PASTE(VAR_,_regName);

#include "allRegister.inc"

#undef REGISTER

typedef uint8_t (*tfnRegistercallback)(tsRegister const *pRegister);

typedef struct {
  uint8_t registerIdx;
  uint8_t registerSize;
  tfnRegistercallback readCallback;
  tfnRegistercallback writeCallback;
  void *pData;  // This is a pointer to the data of the register (in RAM)
} tsRegister;


// Creating of the array of all registers
#define REGISTER(_type,_regName,_readCallback,_writeCallback) \
    {_regName, sizeof(_type), _readCallback,_ writeCallback, &PASTE(VAR_,_regName)},

// Array of all registers, resides in Flash
static const tsRegister allRegister[] = {
#include "allRegister.inc"
};

#undef REGISTER
```

It creates for each register a variable like `static uint8_t VAR_MR_SET_VOLTAGE;`
and an array-entry for each register.

```
static const tsRegister allRegister[] = {
   { MR_SET_VOLTAGE, sizeof(uint8_t), readFnA, writeFnA, &VAR_MR_SET_VOLTAGE},
   ...
};
```

And the callback functions get a pointer to the const entry of the register, so the function itself can be used for multiple registers.

```
void readCallback(tsRegister const *pRegister)
{
  int value;
  if (pRegister->registerSize == 1 )
    value = *(uint8_t*)pData;
  else if (pRegister->registerSize == 2 )
    value = *(uint16_t*)pData;

  if ( pRegister->register == MR_ACT_VOLTAGE )
    doSomething();
}
```